# MySQLdb not setting tables to UTF-8

Tags: python, mysql, django-models, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I specify that the db should be `utf8mb4`:

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MY_DB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

I then run a script to create tables and populate the tables from some flat files. The files have `latin1` characters and are opened with `latin1` encoding.
The tables for the db are specified in `models.py` files, as this is a `Django` app. Django docs say you specify encoding as I did when creating the database.

The data loads, but in MySQL Workbench it looks like the tables are 'latin1':

```
SELECT
`tables`.`TABLE_SCHEMA`,
`tables`.`TABLE_NAME`,
`tables`.`TABLE_COLLATION`,
`collations`.`character_set_name`
FROM
`information_schema`.`TABLES` AS `tables`,
`information_schema`.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` AS `collations`
WHERE
`tables`.`table_schema` = DATABASE()
AND `collations`.`collation_name` = `tables`.`table_collation`
;
```

[query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAHQe.png)

Why does it appear the tables are `latin1` and how can I make them `utf8mb4`?

Comment: This depends on your create table syntax and your global MySQL encoding. The global default will win over if nothing specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `CREATE DATABASE...` command was being called in two places. I was editing the second one, which wasn't being used because the database already existed. When I added `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` to the first `CREATE DATABASE` command, the tables got the correct character set.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query .

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to have to do it for every table..and I'd like to understand why, under the hood, the tables are not using the character set of the database.

Answer (score 0):

The table's charset and collation do not matter; it is only a default that is used when adding new columns.  What matters is the column's settings.  Use this to find out:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable
```

(There is a way to get the information en masse using `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`.)

How was the data loaded?  If you (or Django on your behalf) used `LOAD DATA INFILE`, then did it have a `CHARACTER SET` clause?  It needs such to say what the encoding of the *data* is.  This does *not* need to be the same as the charset for the columns the data will go into.

Further Django notes:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
my.cnf:

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

And Python notes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python